# How to handle events on the dynamically loaded user control?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have the user control that is loaded dynamically. When the user save the data by clicking on the Save button, a raise event is passed.

```
Public Sub RaiseCloseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Close(sender, e)
    Debug.Print(String.Format("The control {{0}} was closed by {{1}}.", Me.Name, sender.ToString))
End Sub
```

In the save button I have called the RaiseCloseEvent as follows:

```
RaiseCloseEvent(sender, e)
```

Now, how can I close the user control form? Any Idea? I have used VB.Net language.

Comment: @Edwin de Koning : This is a Winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Me.Parent.Parent.Controls.Remove(Me.Parent)
```

if your control is added in a tab control.

or

```
Me.Parent.Controls.Remove(TryCast(Me,UserControl))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

-> Obtain the parent control, let's assume this is a panel called pnlParent
-> Obtain the index of the user control in that parent

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl) pnlParent.children.Controls[index]
uc.Dispose()
pnlParent.children.Controls[index].Remove()
```